# got error "Unfortunately app(app name) has stopped" when add footView to the ListView

Tags: android, listview

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
    getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    TextView footerView =  (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view,null);
    ListView list=getListView();
    list.addView(footerView);
}
```

The Activity class extends ListActivity. 
   The problem shows up after I add the last line. I follow standard example and have no idea what caused this bug.
 Please help.

Comment: You should use list.addFooterView(footerView);

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this line:

```
list.addView(footerView);
```

By this one:

```
list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

For a listView, the addView(View view) method:
This method is not supported and throws an UnsupportedOperationException when called.